# undefined method `railties_load_path' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, rails-i18n

I am creating a production database, but when I run the rake db:create I get this error:

```
rake db:create --trace

** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `railties_load_path' for I18n:Module
```

the code showing the error is gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:589:in `block in '

```
   initializer :add_locales do
      config.i18n.railties_load_path << paths["config/locales"]
    end
```

Now when I initially set up I18n, there was no initializers/locales created or anything telling to me do so, but I feel like this is telling me I need one.  I don't know the best way to fix this problem.

IN my searches there was something about this conflicting with will_paginate that I have on here, but no solutions on how to fix it or how it is really conflicting.

my config/application.rb looks like this:

```
module MyProjectName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2

    I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]

    I18n.available_locales = [:en, :he]

    config.time_zone = 'Jerusalem'

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.
  end
end
```

So this is happening across all my projects.  Not sure what I did, I didn't intentionally change anything.
Here is the full error message I get:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\RubyMine 2018.2.2\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\ruby.exe C:/Users/Raja/RubymineProjects/JustinProject/bin/rails server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:589:in `block in <class:Engine>': undefined method `railties_load_path' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    from C:/Users/Raja/RubymineProjects/JustinProject/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:in `new'
    from config.ru:in `<main>'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Users/Raja/RubymineProjects/JustinProject/bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Raja/RubymineProjects/JustinProject/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.2.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
```

Comment: Did you upgrade an existing app to the new version? Open up your `Gemfile.lock` file. What version of the `i18n` gem are you using. I think you might need to `bundle update i18n`. I generated a new 5.2.3 app, and it is using `i18n (1.6.0)`.

Comment: I didn't intentionally upgrade to a newer version but now all of my servers are broken.  I tested loading previous projects to the local host and they are all giving the same error.  I am trying to make sure that everything is lining up but it still causing problems.  Right now I am running Ruby 2.4.4, Rails 5.2.3 and Railties 5.2.2 and it still won't launch.

Comment: I added the full error message I get when I try to start up a server

Comment: The version of Rails and Railties should be exactly the same, and the Booting message says `Rails 5.2.2.1 application starting in development` at the bottom, so I think you might be trying to boot up a 5.2 application with 5.3 installed or vice versa. Since it's being launched from RubyMine, you might need to reconfigure it for this version, or use command-line to bundle and boot up your server.

Comment: I am still getting the error with the rails in my gem file is 5.2.2 and the server is trying to start with rails 5.2.2.  

I tried starting a new project to see and I can't even run rake db:create without getting the error.